# Parse javascript deleteAll() only deletes 20 objects even though my limit is 1000?

Tags: javascript, object, parse-platform, limit

I'm trying to delete images off the server that's been there for more than 1 day, but for some reason it only deletes 20 images even though I set the limit to 1000.

Here's the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteImages", function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    //Get yesterday
    var ts = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var tsYesterday = ts - (24 * 3600);
    var dateYesterday = new Date(tsYesterday*1000);

    //Query with limit 1000
    var query = new Parse.Query("image");
    query.lessThan("createdAt", dateYesterday);
    query.limit(1000);


    query.find({
        success: function(result) {
          Parse.Object.destroyAll(result, {
            success: function() {
              status.success("Delete job completed");
              console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function(error) {
              if (error.code == Parse.Error.AGGREGATE_ERROR) {
                for (var i = 0; i < error.errors.length; i++) {
                  console.log("Couldn't delete " + error.errors[i].object.id +
                    "due to " + error.errors[i].message);
                    status.error("Delete error :" + error);
                }
              } else {
                status.error("Delete error :" + error);
                console.log("Delete aborted because of " + error.message);
              }
            },
          });
          status.success("Delete job completed");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Error in delete query error: " + error);
            alert('Error in delete query');
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated! 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the success message?  Why not include results.length in that message to see what's being sent to deleteAll()?

Comment: Added it, and it says it does a 1000 objects.
Result: Delete job completed1000

Comment: And it only deletes 20 objects. Just now went from 1.6k to 1.58k. I really can't see why!

Comment: Hmm.  And the number actually deleted varies a little bit each time?  I would take that as evidence of timing out.  Especially suspect if you have before or afterDelete hooks running.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, it does delete consistently 20 images even though the query returns 1000 objects.
http://imgur.com/NiEOiNB
I'm a complete n00b in javascript (no experience at all in fact, I just need it for this project). What do you mean with before or afterDelete hooks?

Comment: I'm not using any webhooks, I just realized.

Comment: Right.  Both the presence of web hooks and small variances in the actual count deleted would reinforce a timeout hypothesis.  It might still be a timeout, but less likely given what you report. I don't see any problem in the posted code that would cause the result you're seeing

Comment: Hmm..you seem very competent. This might seem stupid, but if you want, I can give you my password and username and you can see for yourself. In return I can give you points for answered question and an upvote. Aaaaaand all the thanks in the world. My email is enstulen@gmail.com, I don't have enough points to chat..

Comment: Let's try limiting the query to 50.  Does it then report completed 50, and delete 20?

Comment: Yup, deletes 20 yet logs 50.

Comment: Would be happy to help more, but I'm stumped.  I don' think I'd do much better with access to the account, either.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time, though! Really appriciate it :)

Comment: I found [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/parseobjectdestroyall-doesnt) claiming a bug in `destoryAll`.  Can you try setting `{wait: true}` and see if it works?

Comment: Parse.Object.destroyAll({wait: true}, result, {
Like so?

Comment: @MortenStulen The `wait: true` would go into the options object you are passing as your 2nd parameter to `destroyAll`, along with `success`, `error` etc.

Comment: Still no luck :( It keeps deleting 20 images.

Comment: I solved it by using destroy function and not destroyAll. Not the solution I was opting for, but I guess it'll do. I really appriciate the help from both of you :) If you want some points, I'll accept an aswer and upvote it.

Comment: @MortenStulen - glad you found a workaround.  I'd be happier to see your answer than mine.  Feel free to post it here so others can benefit.  The original problem is still very puzzling.

Comment: Would also be interested in a test of that claim discovered by @JamesMontagne.  Strange, if true, that it wouldn't have been fixed by parse by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing the same issue, the solution was really weird and I don't understand why it works. However, by removing the status.success() from the code entirely seems to get the job done. I get an error saying " Failed with: success/error was not called" yet it still deletes 1000 images.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteImages", function(request, status) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    //Get yesterday
    var ts = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var tsYesterday = ts - (24 * 3600);
    var dateYesterday = new Date(tsYesterday*1000);

    //Query with limit 1000
    var query = new Parse.Query("image");
    query.lessThan("createdAt", dateYesterday);
    query.limit(1000);


    query.find({
        success: function(result) {
            Parse.Object.destroyAll(result, {
                success: function() {
                    console.log("Success");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    if (error.code == Parse.Error.AGGREGATE_ERROR) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < error.errors.length; i++) {
                            console.log("Couldn't delete " + error.errors[i].object.id +
                            "due to " + error.errors[i].message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Delete aborted because of " + error.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Error in delete query error: " + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a post exactly related to your issue.

https://parse.com/questions/background-job-remove-all-objects-for-user

"Calling status.success() or status.error() at any point will terminate the job."